# Prevent enter key from triggering button

Tags: jquery, ember.js, preventdefault, enter

I have a search input box which when a user presses enter needs to do nothing. I am using EmberJS and Jquery with the below code. Currently it works to disable a pop up from being triggered but for some reason in IE9 when enter is pressed a toggle button becomes in focus. Works fine in Chrome. I've tried tabindex and preventDefault but neither do the trick.

```
   if ($el.hasClass('form-control')) {
                    if ( e.which == 13) {
                        this.get('controller').flipit();

                    }
                }
```

Thank you.

EDIT------

Here is a snippet of my page. When a user hit enter within the search box the button to the right is getting highlighted. How would I prevent this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do this**

```
$("#inputBox").on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.key == "Enter") event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I am able to detect enter being pressed fine. The problem is that when enter is pressed it is selecting an unwanted button in IE9. So am trying to figure out how to disable enter on detection or basically doNothing when enter is pressed? Maybe have the text box re-selected when enter gets pressed?

Comment: doesn't quite work, for some reason preventDefault isn't doing anything.

Comment: Thanks man figured it out! Sorry being such a noob I had it within the wrong curly braces. Added the code below with what I ended up with.

Comment: Awesome man.  I just edited the code above and this should have worked for you too!

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
   if ($el.hasClass('form-control')) {
                    if (e.key == 13) {
                        this.get('controller').flipit();
                    }

                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;

                }
```