# How to execute event when user presses return on web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET website and I have a forgot password page where the user enters their email address in a text box and when they click the button to retrieve password, the event runs as fine.

Only problem is if the user types in their email address and presses ENTER instead, it runs a search  (I have a search bar at the top of the page) and so the result comes back as 'search query not found'. But this search bar at the top is on a different ASP.NET page.

So anyway, I want the event `onclick` to run when the user presses enter and not run a search query. Does anyone have any ideas? I've searched on this site but not really found the answer I need.

Comment: Maybe something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240364/prevent-enter-key-from-triggering-button

Comment: Are your Email Address text box and Submit button located in the same <form>?

Comment: What was wrong with the other answers you found? Especially the one @rene found?

Comment: Theyre not in a form at all, actually. I think the page is inherited somewhere else. A lot of the things on the page itself are from another location (page) like for example, the search box I have at the top is located elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah have you tried putting them into a form?

Comment: Is it a webform? If so is your password wrapped in an asp:panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple ways you can do this. If it is a webform and you have your textbox wrapped with an asp:panel you can do as below:

```
<asp:Panel ID="p" runat="server" DefaultButton="myButton">
  <%-- Text boxes here --%>
  <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

If its not a webform or you want to move away from that try below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeypress="return EnterEvent(event)"></asp:TextBox>    
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style="display:none" Text="Button" />

function EnterEvent(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            __doPostBack('<%=Button1.UniqueId%>', "");
        }
    }
```

And in the codebehind fire your button click in the page load based on the parameters of the postback.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the "defaultbutton" property to the ID of  (event you want to fire).

You can specify the "defaultbutton" property at the Form level (in the form tag)

Or else you can define them at panel level in the  tag.

The form level setting is overridden at the panel level setting. 
The Event Handler for the specified button gets fired simulating a true submit button functionality.

```
<form id="sampleform" runat="server" defaultbutton="button1">

<div>

<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="button2" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="Button2_Click" />

<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Ok" OnClick="button1_Click" />

<asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" defaultbutton="Button5">

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Button5" OnClick="Button5_Click" />

</asp:Panel>
</div>
</form>
```

In this example, Button1 is the default button for the form (Type something in Textbox 1 and hit enter, button1_Click gets fired). But for "Panel 1", default button will be Button 5 (Type in Textbox3 or Textbox 5 and hit enter).
You can have any number of panels with different default button for each panel.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an ASP Panel around the text box and button with the id of the button name as the property for DefaultButton was the best way to do this.

```
    <asp:Panel ID="p" runat="server" DefaultButton="myButton">
  <%-- Text boxes here --%>
  <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```